# Definition of 'event' & Random Variables with multiple outcomes - probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

In my introduction to probability course, it says that a sample space is a set of outcomes for a scenario or experiment, such that **one and only one outcome will occur**. And that an event is simply a subset of these outcomes. Now, pick a real world scenario and say you want to do some probability & statistics investigations on it, and so you want to analyse it so it fits in with the above context.

E.g. roll a regular dice and your event will simply be your score, and it will be only one of {1,2,3,4,5,6}. But you could also have your events being {prime, not a prime}, {3 or 5, neither}, {2,3,4,other} etc. All mutually exclusive outcomes (and so only one from your event will happen), that work with the above definition.

But what if you had a game of rolling a dice, where if you land {1,2,3} Player 1 gets a point, but if you roll {4,5,6} Player 2 & Player 1 both get a point? Now I'm confused as to whether this is an 'event' or not, as defined above (though my instincts tell me it is, under the right circumstances).

For example, if you were to try and define an event of outcomes as {Player 1 scores, Player 2 scores} this would of course not be an event - because one *or both* of my outcomes could happen. But if you define an event for this game as being {Player 1 scores, both score} that would work perfectly - one and only one of those two outcomes will occur.

This motivates me to conclude then that given a real world scenario, it's your particular analysis that may or may not hold up to the definition of an event, a sample space, an outcome, etc, rather than strictly the scenario itself? Is this all correct - is my take on what are/aren't events in the above scenarios right, or am I missing something?

---

This brings me now to the linked problem with the definition of random variables. My introductory course tells me a random variable X is a **function** from the sample space to some set.

Let me redefine the above scenario in this fashion: say I defined the score of 1-6 on my dice as my sample space, and X maps {1,2,3} and {4,5,6} to {Player 1 scores, both score} respectively. Now again, in this case everything works fine - we've got a bijection between my two events and two final scores, thus X is a function, and so a r.v.

But what if I had the exact same scenario but now defined X as mapping {1,2,3} with 'Player 1 scores' and {4,5,6} with **both** 'Player 1 scores' & 'Player 2 scores' in {Player 1 scores, Player 2 scores}.

Now, with the exact same setup, and the same players scoring the same points, X is a many-one variable, so not a function and not a random variable.

I conclude again that if you want to do a load of probability and statistics calculations on a scenario, it's not necessarily the scenario itself that may not fit the definition of an event/r.v./etc (though I'm sure there are many real world situations that are undefineable in this way) and be unexaminable, but rather your interpretation of the scenario?

Have I understood correctly what is/isn't an 'event', a random variable, etc, and how their definitions work? Thanks so much!

Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

A random variable is a function from the sample space to a **measurable set** $S$, not just any set. As a starting point, we typically  take $S$ to be the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. So the way you defined the random variable is incorrect.

What you could do, for example, would be to consider $2$ random variables $X_1$, player 1's score and $X_2$, player 2's score. Depending on the outcome of the die roll, they could take the value $0$ or $1$. Of course, the way you define what random variable to consider depends on the problem you're trying to tackle. You could just as well consider another random variable $Y$ which is the sum of both players' points. So it would equal $1$ if the roll was either of $\{1,2,3\}$ or $2$ in case of $\{4,5,6\}$.

As for the definition of events, you could define outcomes in terms of the random variable as well: like $\{X_1 = 1, X_2 = 0\}$, $\{X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1\}$, which are mutually exclusive. In such a case, an *event* could be something like "Player 1 scores a point" or $X_1 = 1$, and such an event would consist of both the above outcomes.

Comment: Thanks very much, really appreciate it. A couple points, though: I'm trying to clarify when one's attempt to define an r.v. will fail, based on the definition that an r.v. is a function, and thus not a one-many mapping. Let me change the rules of my game above slightly to say that landing {4,5,6} scores 1 for P1, but 2 for P2. If I choose to say X is the 'scores after each roll' then {1,2,3} again maps to '1' from {1,2} but {4,5,6} now maps to **both** '1' and '2'. Defining X like this means it's not an r.v. because X is now a one-many mapping - is this right? Thank you very much. (P1/?)

Comment: And so, assuming I'm correct on the above as to why that attempted definition of an r.v. would fail, you would have to come up with a diff design for your r.v. (or maybe split them up as in your idea of X1 and X2) so each attempt at an r.v. now is a one-to-one or many-to-one mapping? Many thanks, indeed!

Comment: You'll have to explicitly specify **whose** scores $X$ represents after a roll. If it represents player 1's score (call it $X_1$ instead of $X$), then it maps to $1$ for any roll. If it represents player 2's score (call it $X_2$ instead of $X$), then it maps to $0$ if the roll is from $\{1,2,3\}$, otherwise it maps to $2$. If you really want a random variable that captures information about both players' scores, you'll have to use a random vector: define $X=(X_1, X_2)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable for more info.

Comment: Ok thanks, great - I think the random vector clears up the idea of different players' scores. Quickly though, just to clarify - am I right in thinking an r.v. must be a one-to-one or many-one mapping, otherwise it's not an r.v.?

E.g. imagine a 1 player game - you roll the dice and the outcome = your score (X). But, say landing 6 scores you 6 plus the **separate** bonus of 10 - X thus maps {1,2,3,4,5,6} to {1,2,3,4,5,6,10}. X is thus not an r.v. I could ofc just say hitting 6 scores me a total of 16, making X now a one-to-one mapping, and so an r.v. Is that correct? Thanks very much!

Comment: Random variables are functions and functions can't be one-to-many at all. As for your example, if you land $6$, you **have** to map that outcome to a single value of the random variable (say $10+6 = 16$). So $X$ would map $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5,16\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your example *sample space* was $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with each element being an *outcome*.  Then *events* correspond to elements of a sigma algebra on subsets of the sample space, which with a finite sample space can be all subsets of the sample space

- *Player 1 getting a point* is an event corresponding to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$
- *Player 2 getting a point* is an event corresponding to $\{4,5,6\}$
- *Both getting a point* is an event corresponding to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \cap 
  \{4,5,6\} =\{4,5,6\}$
- *Player 1 getting a point and player 2 not* is an event corresponding to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \backslash \{4,5,6\} = \{1,2,3\}$
- *Neither getting a point* is an event corresponding to $\{\}$

Some of these events are mutually exclusive and together span the sample space, such as the third and fourth, or the first and fifth

Comment: Thanks very much, really appreciate it. Unfortunately though the sigma algebra stuff is completely over my head, as this is only a bare-bones introductory course. To clarify though, am I right in saying that given a scenario, one's definition of an 'event' must include that its outcomes are all mutually exclusive?

For example, say I split a square into 4 quadrants. I throw a Frisbee, and try to define the event it lands {1,2,3,4}, with each outcome being the quad it could land in. My r.v. X is my score per throw, and simply equals the number of the landed quad. (P1/2)

Comment: Now comes the problem: I'm a bad thrower, so the Frisbee lands partly in q-1 and partly in q-2. Here my scenario has now achieved 'two outcomes at once', hence my attempt to define my 'event' as above has proven to be incorrect, because an event for a scenario is where 'one and only one of its outcomes happens'. Is that all correct?

Finally, with the r.v., let me change the rules to say q-2 scores me 2 plus a separate bonus of 5 points. X now maps to the set {1,2,3,4,5}, particularly mapping '2' to {2,5}. This would break the rule that X has to be a function, so not an r.v., right? P(2/2)

Comment: Extra* But, I could rescue X by saying landing in q-2 scores simply scores me '7', so that now X maps {1,2,3,4} to {1,3,4,7} - X is now a function again, and so an r.v. Is that all correct? It may seem like a very avoidable technicality, but I'm trying to get to grips with the rigour of the definition, as it's been quite confusing elsewhere.

Thanks so much, really do appreciate it!